# Faulted State error while creating component with Core Service

Tags: tridion

I get a "faulted state" error when working with the Core Service in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. What's wrong with the following?

```
namespace coreservice1
{
      public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
      {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        try
        {

            using (ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService> factory =
      new ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService>("wsHttp_2011"))
            {
                ISessionAwareCoreService client = factory.CreateChannel();
                string SCHEMA_URI = "tcm:7-426-8";

                var schemaFields = client.ReadSchemaFields(SCHEMA_URI, true, new ReadOptions());
                foreach (var field in schemaFields.Fields) 
                { 
                    Response.Write(string.Format("{0}", field.Name));                         
                } 
                Response.Write(schemaFields.NamespaceUri);
                string NEW_COMPONENT_FOLDER_URI = "tcm:8-15-2";

               Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ComponentData component = new Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ComponentData
               {
                   Schema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = "tcm:8-426-8"},
                   Title = "Helloworldalll",
                   Id = "tcm:0-0-0",
                   LocationInfo = new LocationInfo
                   {
                       OrganizationalItem =
                           new LinkToOrganizationalItemData { IdRef = NEW_COMPONENT_FOLDER_URI}
                   },
               };

               string namespaceUri = schemaFields.NamespaceUri;
               System.Text.StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
               string First = "Hello World.This is Fisrt field";
               content.AppendFormat("<{0} xmlns=\"{1}\">", schemaFields.RootElementName, namespaceUri);
               content.AppendFormat("<{0} xmlns=\"{1}\">{2}</{0}>", "first", namespaceUri, First);
               content.AppendFormat("</{0}>", schemaFields.RootElementName);
               component.Content = content.ToString();
               ComponentData comp = (ComponentData)client.Create(component, new ReadOptions());
               string newlyCreatedComponentID = comp.Id;
               Response.Write("Hello hai");
               Response.Write("Id of newly created component: " + newlyCreatedComponentID);
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
            Response.Write("exception is " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
  }
}
```

> “at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.TypedServiceChannelFactory`1.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.System.IDisposable.Dispose() at coreservice1._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\SampleProjects_Tridion\test\coreservice1\coreservice1\coreservice.aspx.cs:line 73exception is The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.“

Comment: "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."

This means there was an error executing your code and you didn't handle it properly.

Can you share the code you used? Also worth checking this post from Peter: http://pkjaer.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/core-service-clients-and-the-using-statement/

Comment: @NunoLinhares. I have updated the code. Plz have alook at it.

Comment: The code is quite helpful. Can you please point out which line is #73? The error message points to line 73, but I can't map it back to this code fragment.

Comment: @Frank The problem was not at line no 73. The problem was with authentication for anonymous and windows users. I enabled authentication for Anonymous and windows users. Then the error was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I think this might be to do with the way you instantiate your client object.

You can add this as Service Reference in Visual Studio:

e.g. Add Service reference to http://{your tridion url}/webservices/CoreService.svc and give it a namespace of TridionCoreService, then you can use it like this:

```
TridionCoreService.CoreService2010Client client = new TridionCoreService.CoreService2010Client();
```

Alternatively you can use the method [here](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithoutConfigFile) which allows you to create a Core Service reference without needing a config file.

Answer (score 4):

Does it actually create the component? Do you get that far?

I normally write a wrapper class for CoreService, implement `IDisposable` and use the following methods in it:

```cs
private void InitializeClient()
{
    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647 };
    XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quota = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
    {
        MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
        MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
    };
    binding.ReaderQuotas = quota;
    _client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(binding, _endpointAddress);
    if (_client != null) _coreServiceVersion = _client.GetApiVersion();
}
```

and

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
    {
        _client.Abort();
    }
    else
    {
        _client.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sending an example I created time ago in case that helps.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CoreWebService.ServiceReference1;

namespace CoreWebService
{
    class CoreWebServiceSamples
    {

        public static void  createComponent()
        {
            string schemaWebDavUrl = "/webdav/020%20Content/Building%20Blocks/Content/wstest/wstest.xsd";
            string folderWebDavUrl = "/webdav/020%20Content/Building%20Blocks/Content/wstest";

            CoreServicesUtil coreServicesUtil = new CoreServicesUtil();

            FolderData folderData = coreServicesUtil.getFolderData(folderWebDavUrl);
            ComponentData componentData = folderData.AddComponentData();
            componentData.Title = "This is a Test ..... ";
            componentData.Schema = coreServicesUtil.getLinkToSchemaData(schemaWebDavUrl);

            SchemaData schemaData = coreServicesUtil.getSchemaData(schemaWebDavUrl);

            componentData.Content = xmlUtil.GetNewXmlNode("Content", schemaData.NamespaceUri);
            componentData.Metadata = xmlUtil.GetNewXmlNode("Metadata", schemaData.NamespaceUri);

            componentData.AddSingleField("singlefield", "singlefield sample", schemaData.NamespaceUri);
            componentData = (ComponentData)coreServicesUtil.coreServiceClient.Save(componentData, coreServicesUtil.readOptions);
            coreServicesUtil.coreServiceClient.CheckIn(componentData.Id, coreServicesUtil.readOptions);
            coreServicesUtil.coreServiceClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The CoreServicesUtil.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CoreWebService.ServiceReference1;
using CoreWebService.Properties;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;



namespace CoreWebService
{

    public class CoreServicesUtil
    { 
        public CoreService2010Client coreServiceClient;
        public ReadOptions readOptions;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public CoreServicesUtil()
        {
            this.coreServiceClient = new CoreService2010Client("basicHttp_2010");
            this.readOptions = new ReadOptions();
        }

        public  FolderData getFolderData(string tcmuri)
        {
            FolderData folderData = (FolderData)coreServiceClient.Read(tcmuri,ReadOptions);
            return folderData;
        }
        public LinkToSchemaData getLinkToSchemaData(string tcmuri)
        {
            LinkToSchemaData linkToSchemaData = new ServiceReference1.LinkToSchemaData();
            linkToSchemaData.IdRef = getSchemaData(tcmuri).Id;
            return linkToSchemaData;
        }
        public  SchemaData getSchemaData(string tcmuri)
        {
            SchemaData schemaData = (SchemaData)coreServiceClient.Read(tcmuri, readOptions);
            return schemaData;
        }

   }
}
```

The XMLUtil ....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace CoreWebService
{
    public class xmlUtil
    {

        /**
* <summary>
* Name: enumeration
* </summary>
**/
        public  enum Scope
        {
            Content,
            Metadata
        }


        /**
 * <summary>
 * Name: AddItemLinkFieldGeneric
 * Description: basic method for add component links, multimedia links, keyword field to an XmlElement
 * </summary>
 **/

        /**
        * <summary>
        * Name: getXMLElementData
        * Description: adds a single field to an XmlElement
        * </summary>
        **/
        public static XmlElement getXMLElementData(string dataNode)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(dataNode);
            return doc.DocumentElement;
        }



        /**
        * <summary>
        * Name: GetNewXmlNode
        * Description: returns an xml element based on the name and schema
        * </summary>
        **/
        public static string GetNewXmlNode(string Name, string Namespace)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement xmlElem = doc.CreateElement(Name, Namespace);
            doc.AppendChild(xmlElem);
            return doc.FirstChild.OuterXml;
        }

    }
}
```