# Get type of metadata fields of a Metadata schema

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I want to get the all fields along with type/datatype of the metadata fields of a Metadata schema.

I have written below sample code to achieve the functionality and I am able to get Name, Description etc but could not find any property with type/dataType. If anyone of you have any idea, please suggest...

```
var client = new SessionAwareCoreService2010Client();

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myUserName";
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "myPassword";
client.Open();

if (client.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
{
    var schemaUri = "tcm:1-47-8";
    var fields= client.ReadSchemaFields(schemaUri, true, new ReadOptions());
    var fieldName =   fields.MetadataFields[0].Name;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To know the type of a field, you only need to examine the .NET type of the field.
I typically use an "is" check, but you can also call GetType if you want.

For example:

```cs
var client = new SessionAwareCoreService2010Client();

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myUserName";
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "myPassword";
client.Open();

if (client.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
{
    var schemaUri = "tcm:1-47-8";
    var fields= client.ReadSchemaFields(schemaUri, true, new ReadOptions());
    foreach (var field in fields.MetadataFields)
    {
        if (field is SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData)
        {
            // Do something specifically for single-line text fields
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi peter thanks for your reply, foe others help below is the code for all datatypes possible for a field:-

Comment: MultiLineTextFieldDefinitionData, KeywordFieldDefinitionData, NumberFieldDefinitionData, DateFieldDefinitionData, EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData, ExternalLinkFieldDefinitionData, MultimediaLinkFieldDefinitionData, ComponentLinkFieldDefinitionData

Answer (score 2):

The `ReadSchemaFields` method exposes only the ***definition*** of the fields. So it is essentially a wrapper around the properties you enter while you define the field in a schema.

The Content and Metadata are exposed by `ComponentData.Content` and `ComponentData.Metadata` respectively. But those are exposed as XML strings, so you will have to do your own parsing of them.

If you (understandably) don't feel like that, have a look at this helper class: http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata

You might also want to read my answer to this question: [Updating Components using the Core Service in SDL Tridion 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069726)